# Clean destroy of elements and scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

The question is how do I clean destroy elements and scopes in AngularJS.

I've got a binary tree structure, which is implemented by recursively using the same directive.
I would like to change the binary tree structure and rebuild the tree with directives. This works fine, **but** it seems the old elements and scopes are not removed or destroyed properly.

Unfortunately I haven't found a good documentation on the topic of cleaning and destroying of elements. When should I actually use `scope.$destroy()`. (get element scope children in link does not work) Could you give me a link to a documentation?

The following code should give you an impression of my directive.

```
.directive('mydirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        priority: 1000,
        restrict: 'E', 
        scope: {
            node: '='
        },
        controller: 'mydirectiveController',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            function runLink() {

                // Node
                if ...
                    var pane1 = angular.element('<mydirective node="node.left" />');

                    element.children().remove(); // is not sufficient

                    element.append(pane1);
                    element.append(handler);
                    element.append(pane2);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);

                // Leaf
                else ...
                    element.children().remove(); // is not sufficient

                    $compile(widgets)(scope);
                    element.replaceWith(widgets);
            }
            runLink();

            scope.$watch('', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if ...
                    runLink();
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things... one is, because your scope: is an object in the options to the directive, you have isolate scope. So it's not the same scope as the parent scope.

Also, I believe there is something in the angular directive documentation about certain things not working when the directive can contain instances of itself.  Read through all the links around directives and you should find it easily enough. I just ran into it today.

You generally only need to call $destroy() if you created a new scope as a part of setting up the directive. There are examples of this here on stack overflow.

Comment: The question is not relevant for me anymore. Thanks despite of that.